# iOS 10, UIToolbar background color does not change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitoolbar, ios10

I have an app that's been around since iOS 8. the way it's working is that you have a UITableView and tap on cells to produce a score, depending on the score the UItoolbar at the bottom changes color using this method :

```
func updateToolbarAndLabel(score: Int) {

    if(score <= -1) {
        self.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if(score <= 0) {
        self.toolbar.backgroundColor = .None
    } else if(score <= 9) {
        self.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if(score <= 29) {
       self.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    } else if(score >= 30) {
        self.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    if (score <= 0) {
        self.scoreshow.text = "0"
    } else {
        self.scoreshow.text = (score as NSNumber).stringValue }
}
```

then it's called everytime the table view is tapped with this :

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

thing is, it always worked ever since I built the App, but on iOS 10, it doesn't. simply put the color does not change...

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: same here - did you find a solution?

Comment: Anyone able to solve this issue?

Comment: See my answer above

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to solve it, it's changed to this : BarTintColor, found it myself couldn't find anything in apple docs mentionning it

Use it like this : self.toolbar.barTintColor

edit : there is sometinhg mentionning it now in the GM release docs, see answer bellow

Comment: Like I said, just post the part of you code that doesn't work, I don' know swift 3 but from what i red i could be as simple as having it caleed BarTint instead of barTintColor

Comment: I just finished converting my app to swift 3 and the answer above works on swift 3

Comment: works in swift 4, just need to reference the barTintColor property instead of background color property on your outlet.

Answer (score 5):

This is working in xCode 11 for IOS12 and Swift 4:

```
            self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `barTintColor` does not result in the proper color I want, but the following approach worked for me in iOS 11 / Swift 4.

First, create an image of any size that a solid color of what you would like your bar to be.

After that, use the following extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UIToolbar {
    func setBackgroundColor(image: UIImage) {
        setBackgroundImage(image, forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    }
}
```

The solid color image you created will then be applied as the background of your toolbar, and should perfectly match your desired color.

In this example, I used a 1x1 image with purple:
[image]

Comment: This was the only solution that worked. Setting .tint, and .barTint did nothing, but this is completely against the apple docs. Would this qualify for radar?

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 11 & 12 Swift 4 I'm able to do it with this code:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work on IOS 10 and Swift 3 with this code:

```
let dummyToolbar = UIToolbar()
dummyToolbar.barTintColor = .lightGray
dummyToolbar.sizeToFit() // without this line it doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

Change background colour:

```
toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.musalaDarkBlueColor
```

Change buttons colour:

```
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 15.5, Apple's `UIToolBar` documentation is confusing in this regard, providing only a pretty obscure hint, that `.isTranslucent` has something to do with bar color, and is `true` by default. The missing fact is `.isTranslucent` overrides `.barTintColor`, and needs to be explicitly set to `false` before setting `.barTintColor` will have any effect.

```
// 
// Create toolbar with transparent background:
//
let image1 = UIImage(named:      "lolImage")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let image2 = UIImage(systemName: "x.square")

let button1  = UIBarButtonItem(image: image1 , style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
let button2  = UIBarButtonItem(image: image2 , style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.items = [button1, button2]
toolbar.isTranslucent = false   ⇦ ⇦ ⇦ ⇦  IMPORTANT!!!
toolbar.barTintColor  = .clear
```